# postgres; query to work on a set of IDs found

Tags: sql, postgresql

say I have something like:

```
select id from users where age > 21;
```

this yields

```
12
13
14
15
```

Now I would like the query to not just find those IDs but also do something on them, like:

```
(for each id found):  delete from people where user_id = <the id found>;
```

how do I write that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM people WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE age > 21)
```

More information in the [Postgresql documentation about subqueries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the possibility of using a subquery, you can also use a simple `JOIN` in most cases depending on the cardinality of the relationship in most implementations of SQL. Unfortunately, I don't think that PostgreSQL allows for `JOIN`s in its `DELETE` syntax, but they do have a `USING` clause:

```
DELETE FROM People USING Users
WHERE
    People.user_id = Users.id AND
    Users.age > 21;
```

Please let me know if that syntax doesn't work for you and I'll adjust my answer.